# Simple Neural Network can't learn XOR

Tags: ruby, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to learn about neural networks and coded a simple, back-propagation, neural network that uses sigmoid activation functions, random weight initialization, and learning/gradient momentum.

When configured with 2 inputs, 2 hidden nodes, and 1 it fails to learn XOR and AND. However, it will correctly learn OR.

I fail to see what I have done wrong and so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT:** As stated, I tested with 2 hidden nodes but the code below shows a configuration of 3. I simply forgot to change this back to 2 after running tests using 3 hidden nodes.

network.rb:

```
module Neural

class Network

    attr_accessor :num_inputs, :num_hidden_nodes, :num_output_nodes, :input_weights, :hidden_weights, :hidden_nodes, 
                    :output_nodes, :inputs, :output_error_gradients, :hidden_error_gradients,
                    :previous_input_weight_deltas, :previous_hidden_weight_deltas

    def initialize(config)
        initialize_input(config)
        initialize_nodes(config)
        initialize_weights
    end

    def initialize_input(config)
        self.num_inputs = config[:inputs]
        self.inputs = Array.new(num_inputs+1)
        self.inputs[-1] = -1
    end

    def initialize_nodes(config)
        self.num_hidden_nodes = config[:hidden_nodes]
        self.num_output_nodes = config[:output_nodes]
        # treat threshold as an additional input/hidden node with no incoming inputs and a value of -1
        self.output_nodes = Array.new(num_output_nodes)
        self.hidden_nodes = Array.new(num_hidden_nodes+1)
        self.hidden_nodes[-1] = -1
    end

    def initialize_weights
        # treat threshold as an additional input/hidden node with no incoming inputs and a value of -1
        self.input_weights = Array.new(hidden_nodes.size){Array.new(num_inputs+1)}
        self.hidden_weights = Array.new(output_nodes.size){Array.new(num_hidden_nodes+1)}
        set_random_weights(input_weights)
        set_random_weights(hidden_weights)
        self.previous_input_weight_deltas = Array.new(hidden_nodes.size){Array.new(num_inputs+1){0}}
        self.previous_hidden_weight_deltas = Array.new(output_nodes.size){Array.new(num_hidden_nodes+1){0}}
    end

    def set_random_weights(weights)
        (0...weights.size).each do |i|
            (0...weights[i].size).each do |j|
                weights[i][j] = (rand(100) - 49).to_f / 100
            end
        end
    end

    def calculate_node_values(inputs)
        inputs.each_index do |i|
            self.inputs[i] = inputs[i]
        end

        set_node_values(self.inputs, input_weights, hidden_nodes)
        set_node_values(hidden_nodes, hidden_weights, output_nodes)
    end

    def set_node_values(values, weights, nodes)
        (0...weights.size).each do |i|
            nodes[i] = Network::sigmoid(values.zip(weights[i]).map{|v,w| v*w}.inject(:+))
        end
    end

    def predict(inputs)
        calculate_node_values(inputs)
        output_nodes.size == 1 ? output_nodes[0] : output_nodes
    end

    def train(inputs, desired_results, learning_rate, momentum_rate)
        calculate_node_values(inputs)
        backpropogate_weights(desired_results, learning_rate, momentum_rate)
    end

    def backpropogate_weights(desired_results, learning_rate, momentum_rate)
        output_error_gradients = calculate_output_error_gradients(desired_results)
        hidden_error_gradients = calculate_hidden_error_gradients(output_error_gradients)
        update_all_weights(inputs, desired_results, hidden_error_gradients, output_error_gradients, learning_rate, momentum_rate)
    end

    def self.sigmoid(x)
        1.0 / (1 + Math::E**-x)
    end

    def self.dsigmoid(x)
        sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x))
    end

    def calculate_output_error_gradients(desired_results)
        desired_results.zip(output_nodes).map{|desired, result| (desired - result) * Network::dsigmoid(result)}
    end

    def reversed_hidden_weights
        # array[hidden node][weights to output nodes]
        reversed = Array.new(hidden_nodes.size){Array.new(output_nodes.size)}
        hidden_weights.each_index do |i|
            hidden_weights[i].each_index do |j|
                reversed[j][i] = hidden_weights[i][j];
            end
        end
        reversed

    end

    def calculate_hidden_error_gradients(output_error_gradients)
        reversed = reversed_hidden_weights
        hidden_nodes.each_with_index.map do |node, i|
            Network::dsigmoid(hidden_nodes[i]) * output_error_gradients.zip(reversed[i]).map{|error, weight| error*weight}.inject(:+)
        end
    end

    def update_all_weights(inputs, desired_results, hidden_error_gradients, output_error_gradients, learning_rate, momentum_rate)
        update_weights(hidden_nodes, inputs, input_weights, hidden_error_gradients, learning_rate, previous_input_weight_deltas, momentum_rate)
        update_weights(output_nodes, hidden_nodes, hidden_weights, output_error_gradients, learning_rate, previous_hidden_weight_deltas, momentum_rate)
    end

    def update_weights(nodes, values, weights, gradients, learning_rate, previous_deltas, momentum_rate)
        weights.each_index do |i|
            weights[i].each_index do |j|
                delta = learning_rate * gradients[i] * values[j]
                weights[i][j] += delta + momentum_rate * previous_deltas[i][j]
                previous_deltas[i][j] = delta
            end
        end


    end

end

end
```

test.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

load "network.rb"

learning_rate = 0.3
momentum_rate = 0.2

nn = Neural::Network.new(:inputs => 2, :hidden_nodes => 3, :output_nodes => 1)
10000.times do |i|
    # XOR - doesn't work
    nn.train([0, 0], [0], learning_rate, momentum_rate)
    nn.train([1, 0], [1], learning_rate, momentum_rate)
    nn.train([0, 1], [1], learning_rate, momentum_rate)
    nn.train([1, 1], [0], learning_rate, momentum_rate)

    # AND - very rarely works
    # nn.train([0, 0], [0], learning_rate, momentum_rate)
    # nn.train([1, 0], [0], learning_rate, momentum_rate)
    # nn.train([0, 1], [0], learning_rate, momentum_rate)
    # nn.train([1, 1], [1], learning_rate, momentum_rate)

    # OR - works
    # nn.train([0, 0], [0], learning_rate, momentum_rate)
    # nn.train([1, 0], [1], learning_rate, momentum_rate)
    # nn.train([0, 1], [1], learning_rate, momentum_rate)
    # nn.train([1, 1], [1], learning_rate, momentum_rate)
end

puts "--- TESTING ---"
puts "[0, 0]"
puts "result "+nn.predict([0, 0]).to_s
puts
puts "[1, 0]"
puts "result "+nn.predict([1, 0]).to_s
puts
puts "[0, 1]"
puts "result "+nn.predict([0, 1]).to_s
puts
puts "[1, 1]"
puts "result "+nn.predict([1, 1]).to_s
puts
```

Comment: I'd start debugging by setting up a complete test case that includes the initial weights and derivatives/errors for two examples, then step into the code.

Comment: You should really reduce that to a *minimal* bit of code that explains the problem. What you have here is pretty much an entire application.

Comment: Your program looks like it might be doing something interesting.  But each language has its own conventions, and part of the power of Ruby is its conciseness.  You might bring this question to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Comments on similar posts on SO requested to see OP's code so I decided to post my entire app. However, I agree, it is lengthy and quite frankly I am surprised with the number or responses. Prior to posting, I walked through a test case and verified that the computed values matched the expected values at each step of back-propagation. I'll try with additional test cases and read more on BP to see if I misunderstood the algorithm.

Answer (score 13):

My answer will be not about ruby, but about neural network.
First of all, you have to understand how to write your inputs and your network on a paper. If you implement binary operatos, your space will consist of four points on XY-plane. Mark true and false on X and Y axis and draw your four points. If you to it right,  you will receive something like this [image: http://drawsave.com/1Tj]

Now(maybe you didn't know this interpretattion of neuron) try to draw neuron as a line on a plane, which separates your points as you need. For example, this is the line for AND: [image]
The line separates correct answers from incorrect. If you understand, you can write the line for OR. XOR will be a trouble.

And as a last step of this debug, realize a neuron as a line. Find a literature about it, I don't remember how to build neuron by existing line. It will be simple, really. Then build a neuron vector for AND implement it. Realize AND as a single neuron network, where neuron is defined as your AND, calculated on a paper. If you do all correct, your network will do AND function.
I wrote such a huge number of letters just because you write a program before understanding a task. I don't want to be rough, but your mention of XOR showed it. If you will try to build XOR on one neuron, you will receive nothing - it's impossible to separate correct answers from incorrect. In books it is called "XOR is not linear separable". So for XOR you need to build a two layers network. For example, you will have AND and not-OR as a first layer and AND as a second layer.

If you still read this and you understand what I wrote, then you will have no troubles with debugging network. If your network fails to learn some function, then build it on a paper, then hardcode your network and test it. If It still fails, you build it on a paper incorrect - re-read my lecture;)

Comment: It looks as though the code in question has four nodes arranged in two layers: a middle layer of three nodes, and an output layer of one node.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I didn't read code carefully. So quick answer may be: try to make middle layer from two nodes and rerun your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the answer is - use higher values of learning speed. I use the following `lSpeed = 12.8 / epoch` and about   `100 epoches` for the NN with  `phi(x) = x/(1 + |x|)`

Possible now your NN learn speed just do not have enough "power" to make the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consider Neuroevolution, you may check up the `neuroevo` gem. Run the specs to see it **fit XOR in 15 iterations** (`[2,2,1]` feed-forward network, `XNES` optimizer):

https://github.com/giuse/neuroevo/blob/master/spec/solver_spec.rb

Full disclosure: I'm the developer (hi there!).
I just recently began published my code and am looking for feedback.